# VirtualDocumentRoot but with automatic redirection from example.com or example.com.au to www.example.com and www.example.com.au

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have the following setup in my http.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicalName    Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/sites/%0/_site"
</VirtualHost>
```

It all works great (I have /var/www/sites/www.example1.com/_site, `/var/www/sites/www.example2.com.au/_site`, etc). Adding a site is as simple as adding a directory!

However, I now want to make sure that regadless of what domain was called,  if a user goes to `example1.com`, she will be HTTP redirected to `www.example1.com`.

Is there an easy way to do this without losing the brevity above? I have about 84 hosts, and am trying to optimise my `httpd.conf`...
Merc.

Comment: Is it important that it should be a HTTP redirect, or would it work equally well if both the www and the non-www sites were simply to use the same directory?

Comment: It's crucial that it's a redirect...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to simply create the corresponding directories for the bare domain names and redirect from there with individualized .htaccess files. 
I'm usually quite averse to enabling `.htaccess` files but this might be a good use case. If you don't already allow them, the following will set up the permission to use them in a limited fashion:

```
<Directory /var/www/sites/*/_site/> 
   AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

And then in each directory for a site with a bare domain name an .htaccess file with:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com
```